# Search for multiple filters in JSON using Javascript forEach and indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have data in JSON format in which I need to perform search. There are different tags available and when I click on them it searches in JSON and returns the items which has those tags. For this I am using a js function. It works correctly for the first time but When I push second filter in the function it returns wrong data.

Available Filters are:

**Binding**

- Paperback
- Hardcover
- Audiobook
- Boxed Set

**Category**

- Classic Rock
- Pop
- Pop Rock
- Electro Pop
- Soft Rock
- Rock

**Language**

- German
- English
- French

**Author**

- Male
- Female
- Male/Female

Here is the JSON and code I am using:

```js
var m = {
      "Books": [{
          "title": "Book 1",
          "binding": "paperback",
          "category": "pop",
          "language": "english",
          "author": "male"
        },
        {
          "title": "Book 2",
          "binding": "hardcover",
          "category": "pop rock,electro pop",
          "language": "french",
          "author": "female"
        },
        {
          "title": "Book 3",
          "binding": "audiobook",
          "category": "soft rock",
          "language": "german",
          "author": "male,female"
        },
        {
          "title": "Book 4",
          "binding": "boxed set",
          "category": "rock,classic rock",
          "language": "english",
          "author": "female,male"
        },
        {
          "title": "Book 5",
          "binding": "paperback",
          "category": "electro pop,rock,classic rock",
          "language": "french",
          "author": "male/female"
        },
        {
          "title": "Book 6",
          "binding": "paperback",
          "category": "rock",
          "language": "french",
          "author": "male"
        }
      ]
    }


    // a function which accepts key which is one of binding,category,language,author.
    // the array will be filtered on this key
    function getFilteredElement(key, value) {
        var bookFilter = [];
        m.Books.forEach(function(item){
           var getFilterField = item[key];
           // since the value is a string, so splitting it and creating an array
           var keyArray = item[key].split(',');
           // now checking if the passed value has a presence in the  above array
           if (keyArray.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
               // if present pushed the book name
               bookFilter.push(item.title);
           }
       });
        // returning the array of books
        return bookFilter;
    }

    console.log(getFilteredElement('category', 'rock'))
```

**For e.g.** When I push `category = rock` it returns `Book 4, Book 5 and Book 6` but If I push `category = rock` and `language = french`, the returned result should only be `Book 5` but it doesn't return correct results.

Could anyone please help.

Comment: I works to me, I don't know if your are calling the function from different places

Comment: @David If I push `category = rock` and `language = french`, the returned result should only be `Book 5` but it doesn't return correct results.

Comment: These are my outputs for those calls:

[ 'Book 4', 'Book 5', 'Book 6' ]
[ 'Book 2', 'Book 5', 'Book 6' ]

I think they are right

Comment: btw, [JSON](http://json.org/) is a string. what you have is an array with objects.

Comment: Maybe what you want is to combine both filters?

Comment: @David Yes I need to combine filters.

Comment: please add what you really want.. if you like to get only the ones with the given word, which exacly match, then just use strict comparison. so for both conditzion you get only book6. what you want is a part check or a full check but you give not the condition for it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry if you couldn't understand yet. But an answer has been posted for what I exactly want. I want to progressively add tags to the search filters in order to refine of books.

Comment: that part i have understand, but not if you seach for `'rock'` in `'rock'` and or in `'electro pop,rock,classic rock'`, or in `'soft rock'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an object for `filters` and take the keys the key to search for and the value as excact value for the string.

Properties with commas are splitted and checked.

```js
function getBooks(filters) {
    return array.Books.filter(function (o) {
        return Object.keys(filters).every(function (k) {
            return o[k].split(',').some(function (v) {
                return v === filters[k];
            });
        });
    });
    //.map(function (o) {
    //    return o.title;
    //});
}

var array = { Books: [{ title: "Book 1", binding: "paperback", category: "pop", language: "english", author: "male" }, { title: "Book 2", binding: "hardcover", category: "pop rock,electro pop", language: "french", author: "female" }, { title: "Book 3", binding: "audiobook", category: "soft rock", language: "german", author: "male,female" }, { title: "Book 4", binding: "boxed set", category: "rock,classic rock", language: "english", author: "female,male" }, { title: "Book 5", binding: "paperback", category: "electro pop,rock,classic rock", language: "french", author: "male/female" }, { title: "Book 6", binding: "paperback", category: "rock", language: "french", author: "male" }] };

console.log(getBooks({ category: 'rock' }));
console.log(getBooks({ category: 'rock', language: 'french' }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please allow me 5 minutes so that I could check it for all available conditions.

Comment: I was going to suggest this next. You need a stricter comparison mechanism `===`. `includes()` and `indexOf()` aren't strict enough for what you want.

Comment: Right. This is working as per my needs. I am implementing this in my code.

Comment: Your code works perfect. But I get an error when `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` when I try to push the tags with help of a function.
The code I am using is:
`var runSearch = function() {
    var query = [];
    var keys = [];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i in searchTags) {
        for (var j = 0; j < searchTags[i].length; j++) {
            //category: 'rock'
            query.push(i + ": '" + searchTags[i][j] + "'");
        }
    }
    var queryString = query.join(' , ');
    console.log('{' + queryString + '}');
    return '{' + queryString + '}';
}`

Comment: This returns `filters: "{category: 'rock' , author: 'male'}"` on `console.log('filters: ' + JSON.stringify(filters));` and returns `k : 0` on `console.log('k : ' + k);` 
But when I use static value in function like `getBooks({ category: 'rock', language: 'french' })` this returns `filters: "{author: 'male'}"` and `k : author`

Comment: please add the content of `searchTags`.

Comment: @NinaScholz  `i :author`
`searchTags :{"author":["male"]}` (is an Object)
`searchTags[i][j] :male`

Comment: why do you build objects with strings? why is the value an array? could it have more than one item?

Comment: Well my code uses lots of function to capture data and return values. I changed the `runSearch` to return an object and with your code all works perfectly. Thankyou Once again

Answer (score 2):

Use can utilize [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to create such a filtration system, wherein an `array` of `filters` consisting of `key` `value` pairs can progressively be added to in order to refine an `array` of `books`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Books.
const books = [
  {
    "title": "Book 1",
    "binding": "paperback",
    "category": "pop",
    "language": "english",
    "author": "male"
  },
  {
    "title": "Book 2",
    "binding": "hardcover",
    "category": "pop rock,electro pop",
    "language": "french",
    "author": "female"
  },
  {
    "title": "Book 3",
    "binding": "audiobook",
    "category": "soft rock",
    "language": "german",
    "author": "male,female"
  },
  {
    "title": "Book 4",
    "binding": "boxed set",
    "category": "rock,classic rock",
    "language": "english",
    "author": "female,male"
  },
  {
    "title": "Book 5",
    "binding": "paperback",
    "category": "electro pop,rock,classic rock",
    "language": "french",
    "author": "male/female"
  },
  {
    "title": "Book 6",
    "binding": "paperback",
    "category": "rock",
    "language": "french",
    "author": "male"
  }
]

// Query.
const query = (books, filters) => {

  // filters = [{key: 'category', value: 'string'}..]

  return books.filter((book) => {

    // Found?
    return filters.reduce((found, filter) => {
      if (!(book[filter.key].includes(filter.value))) return false
      return found
    }, true)

  })

}

// Log.
console.log('Category = Rock', query(books, [{key: 'category', value: 'rock'}]))
console.log('Category = Rock + Language = French', query(books, [{key: 'language', value: 'french'}]))

console.log('Paperback', query(books, [{key: 'binding', value: 'paperback'}])) // Paperback.
console.log('Paperback + Male', query(books, [{key: 'binding', value: 'paperback'}, {key: 'author', value: 'male'}])) // Paperback + Male.
console.log('Paperback + Male + Pop', query(books, [{key: 'binding', value: 'paperback'}, {key: 'author', value: 'male'}, {key: 'category', value: 'pop'}])) // Paperback + Male + Pop.
```

Comment: Looks Nice. I am checking the code for all available conditions.

Comment: Aah yep I see what you mean though. You want the filtration to be stricter. ie. 'rock' != 'soft rock'.

Comment: Yes. While testing I used 
`console.log('multiple category', query(books, [{key: 'category', value: 'rock'}]))`
This returns Book 2,3,4,5 and 6 but only Book 4,5 and 6 contains **Rock**

Answer (score 0):

This approach solve your problem:

```
function applyFilters(books, filters) {
    for(let filter of filters) {
        var key = filter[0];
        var value = filter[1];
        books = getFilteredElement(books, key, value);
    }

    return books.map(book => book.title);
}

// a function which accepts key which is one of binding,category,language,author.
// the array will be filtered on this key
function getFilteredElement(books, key, value) {
    var bookFilter = [];
    books.forEach(function(item){
       var getFilterField = item[key];
       // since the value is a string, so splitting it and creating an array
       var keyArray = item[key].split(',');
       // now checking if the passed value has a presence in the  above array
       if (keyArray.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
           // if present pushed the book name
           bookFilter.push(item);
       }
   });
    // returning the array of books
    return bookFilter;
}

var filtersToApply = [["category", "rock"], ["language", "french"]];
var bookFilter = applyFilters(m.Books, filtersToApply);
console.log(bookFilter);
```

Comment: Please allow me 5 minutes so that I could check it for all available conditions.