# only first Filter works when applying multiple filter on a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

[image]
I am listning to user inputs for a filter value and storing them in to an array. 
filters = []
my json data is to be filtered based on the values of the filters array.*But the filters can sometimes be empty if users haven't piked certain filters.

```
filters = ["9999", "91", "2", "5920"]
array = [
        {carID: 38871, carNumber: 5918, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhqD2Y=", postingID: 91,peratingCompanyID:2180
        },{carID: 38872, carNumber: 5919, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhqD2Y=", postingID: 81,peratingCompanyID:9999
        },{carID: 38873, carNumber: 5920, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhqD2Y=", postingID: 91,peratingCompanyID:9999
        }]
```

I want to check if there are values in the filters and then apply all the filters to the json with this code that I got from the link below

```
var filtered = array.filter(o => {
    if (filters[0] && o.peratingCompanyID== filters[0]) {
      console.log(filters);
      return true;
    }
    if (filters[1] && o.postingID == filters[1]) {
      return false;
    }
    if (filters[2] && o.dispatchStatus== filters[2]) {
      return false;
    }
    if (filters[3] && o.carNumber == filters[3]) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
```

I want to return the json who satisfies the above filter which is

```
[{carID: 38873, carNumber: 5920, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhqD2Y=", postingID: 91,peratingCompanyID:9999}]
```

What am I missing here?

link: [Search for multiple filters in JSON using Javascript forEach and indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791730/search-for-multiple-filters-in-json-using-javascript-foreach-and-indexof)

[Second example used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831651/javascript-filter-array-multiple-conditions)

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Try removing the return statement from the if condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript filter array multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831651/javascript-filter-array-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Why do you return false for the other `if` conditions? That is like saying "if it matches then say it did not match".

Comment: what kind of filtering do you want? must all values match, or just a single one?

Comment: Do you want to create a true/false result from all filters merged as one, or do you want to have true/false per filter in the result?

Comment: all values must match as long as they exist

Comment: Typo in the json file `peratingCompanyID` should be `operatingCompanyID`

Comment: Also: Your data does not have "carAndDriverAttributes", and your filter data is of a different type than the input data (string versus number). Please provide a good example with expected output, which we can reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use an object for filtering with the wanted keys and values with the **same data type as the data** in the objects for filtering.

> ```
> filters = {
>     operatingCompanyID: 9999,
>     postingID: 91,
>     dispatchStatus: 2,
>     carNumber: 5920
> }
> ```

The result is a new array without items which have some of the filter values.

The filtering with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) works like an logical AND, where all items have to match.

If only one item has to match, then you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which works like a logical OR.

```js
var filters = filters = { operatingCompanyID: 9999, postingID: 91, dispatchStatus: 2, carNumber: 5920 },
    array = [{ carID: 38871, carNumber: 5918, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhqD2Y=", postingID: 91, operatingCompanyID: 2180 }, { carID: 38872, carNumber: 5919, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhqD2Y=", postingID: 81, operatingCompanyID: 9999 }, { carID: 38873, carNumber: 5920, dispatchStatus: 2, dataVersionNr: "AAAAAAhqD2Y=", postingID: 91, operatingCompanyID: 9999 }],
    filtered = array.filter(o => Object
        .entries(filters)
        .every(([key, value]) => o[key] === value)
    );

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I tried this but it always returns  empty array weather any filter is picked or not.

Comment: maybe the keys of the filter and in the objects do not match or the type of the items do not match. please have a look to spelling and the case of the keys/strings.

Comment: Checked and re done everything but still the same empty array is being returned

Comment: you could check if you take only one filter item and proceed until all items are in the filter object. maybe somthing is not equal in the filter or in the data.

Comment: do you mind to puth the data into the question or at a fiddle to have a look?

Comment: Just added an image id the array from the api,this is the array  I wanted  to apply the filter.

Comment: do you have some asynchron data processing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171320/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-sana).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed solving this using promise as below

```
var filters = {
  operatingCompanyID: "",
  postingID: "",
  carNumber: "",
  carAndDriverAttributes: ""
};
```

the array to be filtered being the var array

```
 function getposting() {
    var resultposting;
    if (filters.postingID) {
      resultposting = array.filter(function(o) {
        return o.postingID === filters.postingID;
      });
    } else {
      resultposting = array;
    }

    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      res(resultposting);
    });
  }

  getposting()
.then(function(result) {
  var resultOcId;
  if (filters.operatingCompanyID) {
    resultOcId = result.filter(function(o) {
      return o.operatingCompanyID === filters.operatingCompanyID;
    });
  } else {
    resultOcId = result;
  }

  return resultOcId;
})
.then(function(result) {
  var resultCarNum;
  if (filters.carNumber) {
    resultCarNum = result.filter(function(o) {
      return o.carNumber === filters.carNumber;
    });
  } else {
    resultCarNum = result;
  }

  return resultCarNum;
})
.then(function(result) {
  var resultAttribute;
  if (filters.carAndDriverAttributes) {
    resultAttribute = result.filter(function(o) {
      if (o.carAndDriverAttributes !== null) {
        return (
          // o.carAndDriverAttributes.indexOf(filters.carAndDriverAttributes) >
          // -1
          o.carAndDriverAttributes === filters.carAndDriverAttributes
        );
      }
    });
  } else {
    resultAttribute = result;
  }

  return resultAttribute;
})
.then(function(result) {
  var resultP;
  if (filters.postingID) {
    resultP = result.filter(function(o) {
      return o.postingID === filters.postingID;
    });
  } else {
    resultP = result;
  }

  return resultP;
})
.then(function(result) {
  updateStatus(result, 0, "freecars");
});
};
```