# How to apply multiple filters to json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, local-storage

Site I'm building has a product page that is dynamically generated. I have three filters (brand, category, condition) that I would like to be able to apply any combination of. I figured out how to do this using CSS but what I would like is for the filtered to apply directly to the JSON file and reload the page.

There are about 25 products in the JSON file but here are 3 for reference

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "category": "electric",
    "condition": "used",
    "justIn": "true",
    "brand": "gibson",
    "year": "1952",
    "code": "456def",
    "img1": "../img/sale/gibson/295-1.jpg",
    "img2": "../img/sale/gibson/295-2.jpg",
    "img3": "../img/sale/gibson/295-3.jpg",
    "img4": "../img/sale/gibson/295-4.jpg",
    "alt": "gibson guitar",
    "title": "Gibson ES-295 1952",
    "price": "6000.00",
    "description": "A beautiful ES-295 with wear you can't fake! The ES-295 was originally produced from 1952 to 1958 and is best known for being the model played by Scotty Moore with Elvis. This particular example plays well with a fantastic feeling neck! The guitar has heavy finish wear with the beautiful greening that you often see on '50s goldtops. Glaser has refretted the guitar and replaced the tailpiece crossbar. The pickguard is missing.",
    "specs": ["Body Wood - Laminated Maple",
              "Neck Wood - Mahogany",
              "Fingerboard Wood - Rosewood",
              "Scale Length - 24.75",
              "Nut Width - 1 11/16",
              "Pickup(s) - Original P-90s",
              "Case - Hard Case"
            ]
  },
{
    "id": "9",
    "category": "electric",
    "condition": "used",
    "justIn": "true",
    "brand": "fender",
    "year": "2010",
    "code": "123abc",
    "img1": "../img/sale/fender/strat-sb-1.jpg",
    "img2": "../img/sale/fender/strat-sb-2.jpg",
    "img3": "../img/sale/fender/strat-sb-3.jpg",
    "img4": "../img/sale/fender/strat-sb-4.jpg",
    "alt": "fender guitar",
    "title": "Fender Stratocaster '59 Reissue",
    "price": "1350.00",
    "description": "A quality '59 reissue Stratocaster. The guitar is in excellent condition and comes with the original brown hard case and case candy.",
    "specs": ["Fingerboard - Rosewood",
              "Pickup(s) - Original pickups",
              "Case - Original Hard Case"
            ]
  },
{
    "id": "23",
    "category": "electric",
    "condition": "used",
    "justIn": "false",
    "brand": "gretsch",
    "year": "1958",
    "code": "123abc",
    "img1": "../img/sale/gretsch/gr-cahb-1.jpg",
    "img2": "../img/sale/gretsch/gr-cahb-2.jpg",
    "img3": "../img/sale/gretsch/gr-cahb-3.jpg",
    "img4": "../img/sale/gretsch/gr-cahb-4.jpg",
    "alt": "gretsch guitar",
    "title": "Gretsch Chet Atkins Hollow Body (6120) 1958",
    "price": "13500.00",
    "description": "A classic 6120 Chet Atkins in excellent condition! This single-cut Grestch is loaded with its original filtertrons pickups which tonally sit perfectly between a humbucker and a tele. The finish is in beautiful condition with a faded orange color. Few guitars sound like a Gretsch and this is a prime example of their most popular model. This guitar was previously owned by Ed King.",
    "specs": ["Top Wood - Maple",
              "Back/Side Wood - Maple",
              "Fingerboard Wood - Rosewood",
              "Scale Length -24.75",
              "Pickup(s) - Original Filtertrons",
              "Case - Original White Case"
            ]
  }
]
```

this function creates the filtered array of products that is saved in local storage. The instruments array will always have all the products. The filters array stores the current filters and the filteredInstruments array only the products matching the filters. This function passes the newly saved filteredInstruments/tempArray to the function that builds the page. My issue is the logic behind the multiple filters. What I have works for one.

filt.key will return either brand, category or condition
filt.id will return the actual filters to those categories

```
static filteredInstrumentsHandler() {
    let filters = InStorage.getFilters("filters")
    let instruments = InStorage.getAllInstruments("all-instruments")
    let filteredInstruments = InStorage.getFilteredInstruments("filtered-instruments")
    let tempArray = []


    if (filters.length) {
      filters.map((filt, index) => {
        let key = filt.key
        instruments.map((inst, index) => {
          if (filt.id === inst[key]) {
            tempArray.push(inst)
          }
        })
      })
      InStorage.saveFilteredInstruments(tempArray)
      inUI.displayInstruments(tempArray)
    } else {
      inUI.displayInstruments(instruments)
    }
  }
```

Comment: A simpler way to achieve that is to print categories in the HTML like so:
`<div data-brand="gibson" data-category="electric" data-condition="used"></div>`

Then you can just toggle between `"display: block"` or `"display: none"` by using JS.

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves, OP says: "I figured out how to do this using CSS but what I would like is for the filtered to apply directly to the JSON file and reload the page." The selector way you've proposed is also applies for JS, so this is not what OP asks for.

Comment: @Guney I've read it so fast that I missed that part of the question. Jeff, take a look into [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791730/search-for-multiple-filters-in-json-using-javascript-foreach-and-indexof).

Comment: appreciate the replies and the link. This will be the first project for my portfolio. Would the CSS method be the more common approach? I've looked at a few other sites and whenever a filter is applied, the page reloads and the url get appended. My goal isn't just to make it work, but also using common methods.